# Which runway for a non-permanent power cable?

Tags: extension-cord, cable-management

This is frustratingly harder than expected. I would like to run a 14AWG (or 12AWG) extension cord from an existing receptacle to a currently de-funct fireplace and put a normal, small fireplace heater in it. Total distance is a bit over 10ft:

[image]

Note that the entire path is next to a baseboard (or the bricks of the fireplace), the opening in the floorplan is a window (not a door).

I do not want to install anything permanent  because I may want to use the fireplace again in the future (it requires some work to be done which I do not have the budget for).
Permanent here means drilling holes for electrical boxes. Small nails to fix a raceway would be ok, even though I’d be hoping to just attach it to the baseboard with some double-sided tape.

It starts with a proper extension cord itself. I definitely want a 14AWG (or 12) because there could be some load on it. I found 14AWG, 15ft at Lowe's/HD but they all had the cable come straight out from the plug. But I need one where the cable comes out with a right angle (when plugged into a wall receptacle, the cable should run downwards).

Does such a cable exist or is it better anyway to [purchase by the foot](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Southwire-By-the-Foot-14-2-300-Volt-CU-Black-Flexible-Portable-Power-SJOOW-Cord-55812199/204725134) and build a custom cable?

I am aware that heaters and such generally should not be used with an extension cord. In my case, this would be a single cord, dedicated to this heater and the wiring as thick as the whole circuit itself (#14). I currently plug it in directly but this neither looks nice nor is it a good idea (tripping hazard).

With respect to running the cable nicely along the wall, I found a [Legrand runway](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Legrand-Wiremold-CordMate-III-High-Capacity-Cord-Cover-15-ft-Kit-Cord-Hider-for-Home-or-Office-Holds-5-Cable-White-C310/205091975) but upon closer inspection, this seems only for voltage wiring (even though a 14/2 extension cord would probably fit and the images even show it). I am looking for something [like this](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Commercial-Electric-5-ft-PVC-Floor-Cord-Protector-in-Black-A91-5K/304220999) but for nicely running it along the wall, not across the floor.

Since this seems hard to imagine I also add a picture. It shows the current setup with the wire which is clearly sub-optimal:

[image]

I am just looking for the best and easiest solution to run this along the baseboard. The section on the baseboard, I'd like to paint white, the section on the fireplace that gray color.

Comment: I do not know much about the wiremould, but it is recommended on here for `120v circuits, for similar problems that you have.   I do prefer using 12 gauge extensions for high power use, a heater should come under high power.  14 gauge is the minimum allowed.

Comment: If you want to use the floor protector on the wall, what's your plan for the part of the cord that would be on the floor?

Comment: A fast search found quite a few extension cords with right angle plugs.  There should be attachments for the wiremould to run regular household cable into a receptacle near the fireplace.  Extensions are for temporary use, the wiremould is more for permanent use.  Running a cable though it is good, running an extension not a good look/remove before inspection type.

Comment: Most extension cords are not rated to be contained in anything (under rugs, too tightly coiled, etc), so running an extension cord in wiremolding is probably a no go because of heat buildup. Particularly for a heater on 14 gauge, which I would not do in the first place.

Comment: @crip659 Which wirenould are you talking about? The one I linked seems to be for non-line voltage only. Others I found are for THHN. I am happy with “permanent” use (depends on the definition of “permanent”), doesn’t have to be an extension cord. But I can’t make holes (including holes for surface mount boxes)

Comment: @JonCuster what’s the right way to do it then, if not extension cord? Which cable and which “runway” to choose?

Comment: @Huesmann this is a misunderstanding. I don’t want to use the floor one on the wall. I wanted to point out that I found a “runway” for use on the floor but not the wall. I’d be looking for something like this BUT for wall (not floor) installation. And, if for whatever reason there is no product, what is the right way to do it?

Comment: One way would be 12 gauge wires in a surface mount raceway (see, e.g., Wiremold).

Comment: If you really are constrained to something temporary as you describe, the proper way is probably to use floor raceways, one toward the corner, another one across the doorway. Or just place the cord along the corner of the floor until it gets to the doorway. And while 14ga will technically carry any heating load that pugs in to a 15A outlet, I'd go 12ga just so the cord stays cool.

Comment: @JonCuster I checked Wiremould but I am not able to find one that seems to be for line voltage cords. Only low voltage or THHN (500/700 series). If I am not supposed to use a normal cord (with plug) I am unclear how to connect it to the existing receptacle and provide a means to plug the load in.

Comment: @KMJ Actually there is no doorway, that’s a window. Let me clarify that in the post. Currently I am just running it next to the baseboard but that’s not stable. Robo vacs for example will always catch it (dangerous). Also with such a raceway I was hoping to paint it with the same color (parts of the wall are white, the part at the fireplace is dark blue).

Comment: So you're willing to paint, but not willing to make any holes? You're really constraining things by doing this. Wiremold 500/700 series products are made for exactly the sort of situation you describe: surface mounting AC wiring. You would be using it with THHN cable though and a box on each end. It does need to be screwed to the wall though.

Comment: @KMJ Yes, willing to paint but no holes. Painting the **conduit**, not the wall. I added a picture as well, I hope this makes it a bit more clear. I assume the box on the remote end will also need to be screwed? I want to use the fireplace again once repaired and I cannot drill holes in the firebox.

Comment: Given the restrictions, why not just a black power strip that will handle 1800 watts. They are inexpensive online and have the 'flat to wall' plugs. No matter what you do, the cord for the electric heater will show.

Comment: @RGHughes but how would you make sure that it will actually run next to the baseboard? And won’t be easily moved by a robo vac, kid or something else?

Comment: Sticky hooks to the baseboard. i.e. Self Adhesive Wire Clips Cable Zip Tie Mounts 3/4" with 6 Inch Zipties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Legrand Wiremold surface conduit sounds like the right stuff.  Not that plastic stuff you linked, it's made of metal.  Launch off a surface conduit starter box assuming the existing receptacle is flush. Run black, white, green THHN wire in it and Bob's your uncle.

Comment: Only catch is that while the fireplace end is great (put a junction box at the end of the Wiremold and put a receptacle in it), the other end is a bit more complicated. To be code compliant can't have any THHN outside the box/Wiremold. So that means putting an extension/surface mount for the existing receptacle so that the Wiremold can get right up to it. Or something.

Comment: Assuming the receptacle is flush mount, the starter box should take care of that @manassehkatz ...

Comment: Got it. It seems the 500 series and such a box is exactly what's installed in my bathroom. Feels really more heavyweight than I hoped but I am considering if this is really the only option. One big issue is the "fireplace end": The surface mount box must be screwed, right? I'd need to drill holes into the firebox which is an issue when I want to use the fireplace again in the future. Also, I added a picture to my question (which I hope shows the setup better). Considering picture and firebox hole issues, would you stay with the Legrand Wiremold THHN suggestion?

Comment: It's going to be Wiremold or an extension cord like you're currently using, given your stated restrictions.

Comment: "The surface mount box must be screwed, right?"  If you use strong double-sided tape, I won't tell :)

Comment: I will accept this as an answer because it seems to be the only "right" way. But I would really appreciate if you added to your answer that there is no simpler way with conduit (e.g., placing an extension cord in a plastic conduit) and that the only other alternative would be some sort of wire clips